# What is the right way on looping arrays

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a script.

```
   $args = array(
    'post_type' => 'cust_type',
    'tax_query' => array(
    'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'category',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => 'term1',
        ),
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'category',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => 'term2',
        ),
    ),
);
```

I want the arrays below the line relation to be loop.

What I have done so far:

```
$keys = array('term1','term2');
foreach($keys as $key) {
    $arcom .= "array(
        'taxonomy' => 'category',
        'field' => 'slug',
        'terms' => '$key',
    ),";
}
```

Is this right?  Am I doing it the right way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did it almost correct

```
$keys = array('term1','term2');
$arcom = array();
foreach($keys as $key) {
    $arcom[] = array(
        'taxonomy' => 'category',
        'field' => 'slug',
        'terms' => $key,
    );
}
```

**Explanation**

Array's can be appended to the end by using `[]` like so `$arcom[]`.

`$arcom[5]` The number between here indicates the key the array will be inserted with, the number can also be replaced with a string or leaving it empty will append the array to the end.

Answer (score 1):

changes required in your code

```
$keys = array('term1','term2');
$arcom = array();
foreach($keys as $key) {
$arcom[]= array(
        'taxonomy' => 'category',
        'field' => 'slug',
        'terms' => $key,
    );
}
```

Comment: i believe this will work too. same answer with @thaillie,  thanks mate for taking time answering it. cheers!

Comment: thaillie, has copied my answer

Answer (score 0):

```
$keys = array('term1','term2');
$arcom = array();
foreach($keys as $key) {
    $arcom_sub_array = array(
        'taxonomy' => 'category',
        'field' => 'slug',
        'terms' => $key
    );
    array_push($arcom,$arcom_sub_array);
}
```

Comment: Please explain your solution a little

Comment: produces: array(0=>'foo', 1=>'bar');  
    $arr[] = 'foo';  
    $arr[] = 'bar';  

    produces: array('foo', 'bar');  
    array_push($arr, 'foo', 'bar');